# Convert two boolean columns to class ID in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, boolean

I have to boolean columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True,  True],
                   [True,  False],
                   [False, True],
                   [True,  True],
                   [False, False]],
               columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

I need to generate a new column that identifies which unique combination they belong to:

```
result = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 0, 3])
```

Seems like there should be a very simple way to do this but it's escaping me.  Maybe something using `sklearn.preprocessing`?  Simple `Pandas` or `Numpy` solutions are equally preferred.

**EDIT**:  Would be really nice if the solution could scale to more than 2 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest is create `tuples` with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
print (pd.Series(pd.factorize(df.apply(tuple, axis=1))[0]))
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    3
dtype: int64
```

Another solution with cast to `string` and `sum`:

```
print (pd.Series(pd.factorize(df.astype(str).sum(axis=1))[0]))
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for.  I knew there was a one-liner in there.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Glad can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used pandas before but here is a solution with plain python that I'm sure wouldn't be hard to adapt to pandas:

```
a = [[True,  True],
       [True,  False],
       [False, True],
       [True,  True],
       [False, False]]

ids, result = [], [] # ids, keeps a list of previously seen items. result, keeps the result

for x in a:
    if x in ids: # x has been seen before
        id = ids.index(x) # find old id
        result.append(id)
    else: # x hasn't been seen before
        id = len(ids) # create new id
        result.append(id)
        ids.append(x)

print(result) # [0, 1, 2, 0, 3]
```

This works with any number of columns, to get the result into a series just use:

```
result = pd.Series(result)
```